# How to convert tiff image with fillorder 2 to pdf without using itext and preferably pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox, bufferedimage, tiff

I need to convert a tiff image to pdf. 
I am currently using pdfbox however

- Either I am getting exceptions due to fillorder
- When I convert the tiff to bufferedImage and then try to convert, I get a corrupt pdf
- When I convert the tiff to bufferedImage and back to tiff and then convert to pdf, I get exception that tiff file is not compress to T4, T6.

I don't have much knowledge on tiff file. So could anyone please assist?

Comment: How did you convert the tiff to BufferedImage and get a corrupt PDF? Please edit and add the code, so that I see whether this is a java bug or a PDFBox bug or a coding error. Same for the 3rd bullet point. Also link to such a TIFF image. And mention whether you got any log messages, and mention what PDFBox version you are using.